# how to synchronize two carousel slider - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have two sliders (twitter bootstrap 3.3.6) on one page. Both should be activated via the same control-elements. When activated through the keyboard arrow-keys - very fast clicks -, I am losing the synchronization; Especially in Firefox (v 49.0.1). That means the image in the header-slider does not belong to the text in the content-slider.

How can I realize, that the slider is only activated when the animation of both sliders has finished?

I have already tried with jQuery-promise(), But the error stays the same.

Thanks for any help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sliderHeader, #sliderPartner').carousel({
    interval: false
  })
  $('#sliderPartner a.left').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".carousel").promise().done(function() {
      $('#sliderHeader').carousel('prev');
      $('#sliderPartner').carousel('prev');
    });
  });
  $('#sliderPartner a.right').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".carousel").promise().done(function() {
      $('#sliderHeader').carousel('next');
      $('#sliderPartner').carousel('next');
    });
  });
  $('#sliderPartner .carousel-indicators li').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var indicatorNumber = $(this).attr('data-slide-to');
    $('#sliderHeader').carousel(parseInt(indicatorNumber));
    $('#sliderPartner').carousel(parseInt(indicatorNumber));
  });
  $("body").keyup(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { // left
      $('#sliderPartner a.left').trigger('click');
    } else if (e.keyCode == 39) { // right
      $('#sliderPartner a.right').trigger('click');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Twitter Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
  <div id="sliderHeader" class="carousel slide">

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        image0
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        image1
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        image2
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        image3
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        image4
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="sliderPartner" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#sliderPartner" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#sliderPartner" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#sliderPartner" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          <li data-target="#sliderPartner" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          <li data-target="#sliderPartner" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <p>Content0</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <p>Content1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <p>Content2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <p>Content3</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <p>Content4</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#sliderPartner" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Zurück</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#sliderPartner" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Vor</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a global variable keeping track of what page you're on.

```
$(() => {
    const MAX_PAGE = 10 // or however many pages
    let pageNum = 0

    goToPage = (newPage) => {
        pageNum = Math.max(0, (Math.min(newPage, MAX_PAGE))
        doPageChange(pageNum)
    }
    next = () => { goToPage(pageNum + 1) }
    prev = () => { goToPage(pageNum - 1) }
})
```